# CEFSharp select input closes and reopens when enter is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I thought I would post this here before going to the issues list at github to see if there may be an solution to the issue.

Problem:  I have a select input with a list of values in a CEFSharp WPF browser, if the select input is open and i press enter, the select options list closes and then re-opens right away.  If i preform the same action in Chrome the selected option in the select box is selected and the select options list is closed.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem using the `cefclient` example app?

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#cefsharp-vs-cef

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the issue with the CEFclient, however i was able to reproduce the issue in the example WPF project in the CEFSharp repo:  testing site - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select . I will open an issue github and see if i might be able to track it down.